# How do you add more fields to auto-populate?

Tags: mongoose

Currently, the user model is like this:

[image]

But I'd like to add another field when they auto-populate the user.
Let's say I also want to see their email for this particular controller.

[image]
^ That didn't work

[image]
^ That didn't work

[image]
^ That didn't work...

I also tried auto-populate: false but out of luck. So how can I append more fields to auto-populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not achieve this with collection.findOne() so I tried collection.aggreegate() and lookup function to fetch all fields of User Model. Hope this helps someone